# wxWidgets + Cygwin on windows

Tags: c++, cygwin, wxwidgets

I am trying to install wxWidgets on Windows.

I unzipped wxWidgets and then followed this guide: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Adding_an_Environment_Variable_under_Windows

I copied their sample hello world source code and tried to compile it using g++ but it tells me `wx/wx.h No such file...`

I am new to C++. Am I doing it right? I followed the guide exactly.

PS: I use cygwin + notepad++

Comment: Where did you install wxWidgets to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cygwin you need to:

1. Build wxWidgets using `configure` and `make`, see the appropriate section of `docs/msw/install.txt` in your wxWidgets installation.
2. Optionally install it using `make install`.
3. Use `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` when compiling your code, just as under Unix (because Cygwin *is* Unix).

P.S. If you're new to C++ you're unlikely to find Cygwin the most newbie-friendly environment.